# Magento 2.3.7 orders mysteriously disappeared

Tags: security, magento2.3.7

I'm hoping this isn't an indication of some kind of breach/vulnerability.

We recently discovered two orders where the buyers attempted to execute php using the ShipTo name. The code meant to append a line to the pub/health_check.php file. It didn't work, thankfully.

I was able to view both of these orders in the backend last week. We received notification from our merchant account that a refund was requested for one of these orders last week as well, and since we show we shipped the product and it was received, we're disputing the refunds.

As of right now I cannot find these orders in the backend. I also checked the DB and they are gone from sales_order_grid. The invoices themselves still exist but when I attempt to view them I see a 404 page not found with a red Magento error ("Invoice capturing error") at the top. There isn't a way for a user to delete an order, right?

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: It is better to secure your pub/index.php and health_check.php files attacker is trying to upload his script in index.php and wanted to change permission of this file but fortunately he has not been succeeded!, you need to quickly review your database major tables like customers, sales orders etc. may be torjan horse code is still their.

also make backup of your code, scan and change your all passwords like admin, server and db.

I faced same situation but I was recovered  safely my website within 15 days and secured it.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the issue is related to user permissions or access controls. If a user with the appropriate permissions was able to delete orders, either intentionally or accidentally, this could result in orders being removed from the system.

Answer (score 0):

We were compromised. I believe these were failed attempts where at some point they succeeded. While health_check.php looked fine last week it has been modified now. A new administrator user was created and changes were made to the file system.